# php - String to int not working properly and just produce zero

Tags: php

I've looked everywhere in the web and do some testing and I can't still understand my code.

```
$hcptype_id = $_GET["asdfghjkl"];
$a = 0 + $hcptype_id;
echo $a;
```

The `$a` produces 0 although the `$hcptype_id` has a value of 4. I've also tried the `(int)$hcptype_id` but still produces 0.

EDITED 
`echo $hcptype_id;
echo $_GET["asdfghjkl"];
var_export($_GET["asdfghjkl"]);`

Produces:
`"4"
"4"
'"4"'`
EDITED AGAIN
`var_dump($_GET);
var_dump($hcptype_id);
var_dump($a);`

Produces:
`array(1) { ["asdfghjkl"]=> string(3) ""4"" } string(3) ""4"" int(0)`

EDITED MUCH AGAIN
The variable `asdfghjkl` comes from another page and it goes this `<a href=sc_hcp_type_edit.php?asdfghjkl="'.$row['hcptype_id'].'">`

Comment: debugging, `var_dump` everything and mybe you will see what PHP is actually doing?

Comment: Ouput var_dump($_GET);

Comment: Note to answerers:  stop guessing as this question includes an obvious mistake.  All answers provided so far either depend on that mistake or don't answer the question directly.

Comment: I can't edit my post because the icons keeps incrementing and lagging. When I do this `$a = 0 + "123";` the `$a` display it just fine.

Comment: @WTFZane:  We all know that.  Show us the output of `var_export($_GET["asdfghjkl"]);` from your example.

Comment: The suspense is killing me.. dump the output already!! :P

Comment: It is `'"4"'` I dont know where is the single quote comes from

Comment: @WTFZane `var_dump($hcptype_id)` does not echo out `'"4"'` but perhaps you should `trim($hcptype_id, '"')` the quotes from 4.

Comment: @Xorifelse:  You wrote the proper solution so you should post it as an answer.

Comment: I don't understand `"4"` is just the same as `$hcptype_id` they both appear as `"4"` but the $hcptype_id produces while the `"4"` do just fine

Comment: @JuliePelletier You can, I prefer not be be affiliated with bad questions <3

Comment: Use my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in your different traces, there are double-quotes (`"`) that prevent it from being parsed as an integer.

One solution is to use `trim()` to remove the offending character: `$hcptype_id = trim($_GET["asdfghjkl"], '"');`.

Comment: There we go, a valid answer

Comment: Hello, please clarify why im having a double-quotes(`"`).

Comment: @WTFZane how can we if you didn't add the HTML code that generates this issue?

Comment: @Xorifelse I've included the anchor link in the latter part.

Comment: @WTFZane Sorry, didn't read the updated, but assuming `$row['hcptype_id']` comes directly from the DB, it is stored as such and again, possibly generated from the html code.

Comment: Ahhh i get it, so it is just the way it is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113347/discussion-between-xorifelse-and-wtfzane).

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure you are retrieving the correct data from $_GET, you don't need to add 0.
Just do this:

```
$hcptype_id = intval(trim($_GET["asdfghjkl"],'"'));
```

Also, As you have wrapped the value in ", I trimmed the double quotation signs

Answer (score 1):

The only way to reproduce the behaviour you describe is that your assumption:

> $hcptype_id has a value of 4

... is not true:

```
var_dump(0 + '4');
var_dump(0 + 4);
var_dump(0 + '04');
var_dump(0 + ' 4');
var_dump(0 + 'foo');
```

... prints:

```
int(4)
int(4)
int(4)
int(4)
int(0)
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/S4AvIgKO)

As you can see, [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump) can be used to inspect PHP variables (type included) and `var_dump($hcptype_id)` will reveal that you don't have a `4` in the first place. From your updated question:

> `string(3) ""4""`

Note: the `(3)` part indicates we have 3 bytes (while only 1 would be expected).

Once here, we can conclude there's a bug somewhere before the code you've shared. While there're many possible workarounds to fix out invalid numbers, such as:

```
$hcptype_id = preg_replace('/\\D+/', '', $_GET["asdfghjkl"]);
```

... the best approach is to go to the source and fix the process that generates the original data. From your descriptions, the root problems seems to be a database column called `hcptype_id` that has at least two potential issues:

1. It has a text column type rather than a numeric one
2. The process that populates it adds bogus quotes

Comment: While obviously you know your way around SO (sole reason I refuse to downvote), how is this an answer that resolves his issue?

Comment: @Xorifelse I know that *here's the code you need to paste into your project* answers are more popular but I find them less useful in general. In this case, since he clearly doesn't a 4 in the first place, what kind of answer should I give?

Comment: Whatever, I've edited my answer to be more specific. If you still feel it deserves a downvote, I'll gladly remove it.

Comment: I've been voted down for better answers than this simply because I didn't wait for the asker to clarify the situation!

Comment: @JuliePelletier Aren't requests for `var_dump()` output ignored 95% of the times?

Comment: Then the question should be flagged.

Comment: The OP has updated the question and he didn't have a 4 as (honestly) we all knew from the beginning. Of course, he's accepted the first answer that provides some code to copy and paste but I can't blame him.

Answer (score -1):

Cast your variable to int using [intval](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.intval.php). You won't need the `0 +` part.

```
$a = intval(trim($hcptype_id));
```

Comment: Please explain why you think it should be tried. Without an explanation then it may as well be some 'magic spell' that gave the correct answer.

Comment: This should do exactly the same as the original code.

Comment: Won't work.

`echo intval(trim("\"4\""));` gives `0` while `echo intval(trim("\"4\"", '"'));` gives 4.